# Fixing issue with queries in MySQL Workbench 8

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I am running a query to update the table however it's not impacting any data. I am doing the below steps:-

1. Created a temporary file in MySQL which has a column accounts.
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempfile (accounts varchar(20));
2. Created a CSV file that has only four account numbers. This CSV file is converted from xlsx format and each data is in a separate row. Look exactly like this-
   22070601
   22070701
   22070801
   21752301
3. Now I have uploaded the above CSV data file to the tempfile using the command
   LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/testaccounts.csv" INTO TABLE tempfile FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
   ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS;
4. I have concatenated '0' to all accounts using the query
   UPDATE tempfile SET accounts = concat('0', accounts) where accounts IS NOT NULL;
5. I have run a query to see the updated data. I see all the account numbers are contacted with '0'
   SELECT *FROM TEMPFILE;

Output:
022070601
022070701
022070801
021752301

6. Later I ran a query to change the status of the accounts to 'A' for all the accounts whose numbers are there in tempfile

update users set status = 'A' where account in (select account from tempfile);

Output: Query is successful but with 0 changes

7. Later I again ran the query SELECT *FROM TEMPFILE;
   The output is copied to a notepad and I see \r concatenated to all the account numbers
   It looks like this

'022070601\r'
'022070701\r'
'022070801\r'
'021752301\r'

I believe because of additional '\r' in account numbers, my query on point 6 couldn't find any similar accounts in tempfile to change the status to 'A';

Someone, please help me on this issue and why there is '\r' in the account numbers when I copied the output to the notpad.
I need to change the status of my accounts to 'A' depending upon the account numbers in my tempfile. All the account number in tempfile need to have leading '0'.

Comment: can you provide a ceate table with inserted data to show clearly your problem. Also you get rid of any characters before inserting it

Comment: Just after uploading the data using LOAD DATA query to the temporary file. I ran the SELECT query  and copied all the account numbers in the output to the Notepad++  and I see they all have again '\r' padded in the end. 
'22070601\r'
'22070701\r'
'22070801\r'
'21752301\r'

I believe there is some issue with my query of using LOAD DATA. I am using this query 
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/testaccounts.csv" INTO TABLE tempfile FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS
Note: All my data in the sheet are in separate rows and they are not separated by ','

Comment: change `FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'` to `FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\r\t'`   (See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14133740/724039 )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE: works, but unpredictable line terminator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935219/mysql-load-data-infile-works-but-unpredictable-line-terminator)

Comment: The issue got resolved after I made all the data to be comma-separated like 12345, 6789 then run the query LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/estaccounts.csv" INTO TABLE tempfile FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ,' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS;
However, still figuring out for the query for non-comma separated (data in each different rows)